Which episode/movie of Naruto is this scene from?
I usually don't watch anime but on Facebook I saw a video where a guy sitting on cliff playing Japanese shamisen (guitar like instrument), converts his tattoos into a metal chain which attacks a group of people passing through.
One of the guy in the group defends them using his power but the chain some how finds him and stab him, forming a link using which the guitar guy sucks powers of his target. 
The guy who was attacked ask his friends to escape, and the guitar guy continues to suck his power by playing music.
Some time later a girl look like fairy, fly to that place to help the victim but the guitar guy attacks her also with his chain.
After that, the girl with wings forms a cocoon around them defending them self's
That's all I can remember.  
Can anyone tell me which anime is this?
I'm pretty sure it is a Japanese anime. 
Edit: After a lot of searching I find out that, it was Naruto anime and the guy who got attacked was Gaara with power of sand.  

This is from In Naruto's Footsteos: The Friends' Paths story arc, from the episode The Targeted Tailed Beast:
Here are two parts of descriptions that have similarities to your description:

"They hear a strange melody and realise that the terrain is not in their favour for an enemy attack. Hōichi animates their shadows, strangling the three in order to call out Gaara. With the jinchūriki's arrival, Hōichi sets his plan in motion and uses his sealing technique to latch on to Shukaku in order to pull him from the inside its jinchūriki."  
"In response to her opponent's technique, the girl creates a cocoon using her chakra threads, which delays the chakra absorption caused by the chains."  

Here is a picture of Gaara being attacked by the chain: 


can you give me link to this video

@Praneeth the picture is from the links, but I think googling or searching the episode name on youtube should find it

Yeah! I tried Youtube first but I didn't get the good video, I searched in FB and I got it thank you!

@Praneeth remember that it's a filler episode and not part of the main story.

@Praneeth Glad to hear it :) You can also accept the answer so that other users know the question is answered.
